# Does the series $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{2k + 1}{2}\pi)}{\sqrt{k+1}}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Determine whether the alternating series
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{2k + 1}{2}\pi)}{\sqrt{k+1}}
\end{align*}

absolutely converges or conditionally converges or diverges. Please show all steps

Comment: Note that $\sin\left(\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi\right)$ is simply $(-1)^k$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Can you show your attempts for to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT.** Note $\sin\left(\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi\right) = (-1)^k$, thus it is an alternating series. All you need to do is to check $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ and $|a_{n+1}|\le |a_n|$.